# Moving home and backup to another partition

Tags: centos, mount, partition

I am on a dedicated server (CENTOS 7.3 x86_64 standard)
I have 2 partitions on 1 drive and my primary partition is full
I would like to move home and backup to the larger secondary partition (`/dev/md127`). Can I rename `/dev/md127`?
Or what would you recommend?
Can anyone give me the steps to do this?

```
Here is my df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       107G   76G   25G  76% /
devtmpfs        7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           7.8G  8.9M  7.8G   1% /run
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md127      1.8T   84M  1.7T   1% /mnt/md0
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/0
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be shinking your `/dev/md127` partition and create a new partition for `home` after it. You can use a boot live CD for this and create the partition using GParted. Don't forget to give to the partition the `home` label.

I advise switching to root first.
In the terminal, enter `su`.

Then, you need to move your files from the folder to the new partition.

```
cd /mnt
mkdir racine
mount -t ext3 /dev/sda1 /mnt/racine
cd racine
ls
```

Then, to copy the folders and files from your "/home" folder to the new "home" partition, people traditionally use one of these commands `dd`, `ddrescue`, `rsync` or `mv`.

Assuming that your are in the "racine" folder and the new partition for "home" is sda6 copying the files should look like.

```
dd if=home of=/dev/sda6 bs=512 count=999999999999
```

or

```
ddrescue -v -f home /dev/sda6 /home/MyPossibleLogFile.txt
```

(Nota bene: I didn't test above commands in for your case. Thank you for your indulgence if I'm missing something, some parameter or else.)

Then, get the UUID of your new /home partition: `blkid /dev/sda6`

Then we need to edit the `fstab` file, to add a line telling about the dedicated `home` partition.

```
cd /mnt/racine/etc
nano fstab
```

Additionally you may have to update GRUB afterwards.

My answer can be improved a lot, but you have the idea.